# Program Activity Home Button to go back to previous Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

After trying so hard to make Home button appear in my ActionBar it finally showed up, but when clicking it nothing happens. What method or OnClick listener should I add to make it functional.
I admit this question has been asked frequently and after going through most of them, am still not satisfied so please moderators take it easy on me, please.
Anyway your help is greatly appreciated.
Here is the code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            
        }
//Method to listen on the home button tap and go back to previous activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button in the upper left of the Action bar is the [Up button](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action). If you've already added the `android:parentActivityName` name to your AndroidManifest, then the system does the correct thing already - navigate you back to that parent activity as per the documentation on the [`onSupportNavigateUp()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity#onSupportNavigateUp()), which is the method that is triggered when that button is clicked.

Comment: Actually lemme experiment on that now, Thanks for thre Answer @ianhanniballlake

Comment: You hit the jackpot with your reply buddy, keep up with the good work. Thanks in Advance. You deserve that upvote...